# How to set toolbar action icon in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs

I am new in React Native. I want to set icon (from `react-native-vector-icons`) for `ToolbarAndroid` action. Here is my JSX code:

```
import ToolbarAndroid from 'ToolbarAndroid';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
...
<ToolbarAndroid
  title='SomeTitle'
  titleColor='white'
  style={styles.toolbar}
  actions={[
    { title: 'Done', icon: 'HERE_I_DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_PUT', show: 'always' },
    { title: 'Setting', show: 'always' },
   ]}
/>
...
```

Name of icon from material design collection is `done`.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using React Native 0.21 and [`react-native-vector-icons`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) 1.3.0 you can now use `iconName` like this:

```
<MaterialIcon.ToolbarAndroid
  title='SomeTitle'
  titleColor='white'
  style={styles.toolbar}
  actions={[
    { title: 'Done', iconName: 'done', show: 'always' },
    { title: 'Setting', show: 'always' },
   ]}
/>
```

Comment: i am not getting how to get position of action in actions array? i want to use that in onActionSelected